# How do I examine if I have properly installed pymunk

Tags: pymunk

I typed "python3 install pymunk" in terminal and seems that it is installed. But how do I, in terminal, examine it is properly installed? I tried to type "import pymunk" in terminal, yet it says

```
-bash: import: command not found
```

When I run pymunk in sublime, it says

```
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (64bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the `import pymunk` from inside the python interpreter, or inside a python file that you run.

So, first you start the python interpretee with `python3` when you are in the terminal and then you can do the `import pymunk` when you are inside python.

Pymunk in a python library, and usually you import the libraries from inside python. If you are a beginner I think it would be good for you to read a beginners guide to python, for example  http://inventwithpython.com or some other intro.